# Return openpyxl workbook object as HttpResponse in django. Is it possible?

Tags: python, django, excel

I need to provide an excel formatted data from django's database to visitors.

The only way I can think of is with these steps:

1. Extract data from database.
2. Wrap it with `Workbook` object from `openpyxl`.
3. Save it somewhere temporarily.
4. Read it again as 'rb'.
5. return view with [excel's mime type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2938188/4019871).
6. Delete excel file on disk. (It's useless now right?)

That should do it. But, I think there's another better way to do this. I mean
maybe there's a way to return `openpyxl` object as `HttpResponse` directly
without intermediate file medium.

So, my question here is: is it possible to return `openpyxl`'s `Worbook`
object? (I'm new with `openpyxl`)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You don't actually need to save the data anywhere on disk; openpyxl has a way to do this, although it's not very well documented. A long while back, I created [something like this](https://bitbucket.org/tarkatronic/django-excel-response) using xlwt, but I recently also built something similar in the [Falcon](http://falconframework.org/) framework, using openpyxl.

Putting these two together, your code would look something along the lines of:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.writer.excel import save_virtual_workbook


workbook = Workbook()
worksheet = workbook.active

# ... worksheet.append(...) all of your data ...

response = HttpResponse(content=save_virtual_workbook(workbook), mimetype='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=myexport.xlsx'
return response
```

If you are generating larger files, I would recommend looking into using StreamingHttpResponse, but I believe this will at least get you going.

This is just an off-the-cuff snippet based on a merge of the two project I worked on, so it may not be exactly correct. It should be pretty close though. The output in Falcon looked like:

```
response.content_type = 'application/octet-stream;'
response.set_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=myexport.xlsx')
response.body = save_virtual_workbook(workbook)
```

**UPDATE:**
This is now much easier, as I did a complete rewrite of my old `django-excel-response` library, using openpyxl! It can now be found here: https://github.com/tarkatronic/django-excel-response

You can install it with `pip install django-excel-response`, and start using it as an alternative to Django's `HttpResponse`! There is minimal documentation included, and improvements/suggestions are welcome. :)

Comment: This other answer might be relevant for future readers... "mimetype" arg has been renamed for "content_type"

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28758787/init-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-mimetype

Answer (score 13):

Since save_virtual_workbook will be obsolete, I used [stream](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#saving-as-a-stream) insted.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

def exportToExcel(request):
   workbook = Workbook()
   ...

   with NamedTemporaryFile() as tmp:
      workbook.save(tmp.name)
      tmp.seek(0)
      stream = tmp.read()

   response = HttpResponse(content=stream, content_type='application/ms-excel', )
   response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename=ExportedExcel-{datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M")}.xlsx'
   return response
```

Comment: NOTE for **Windows users**: Be ready to get the error "[Errno 13] Permission denied". To fix it, do the following steps: 1) First, add the argument `delete=False` for `NamedTemporaryFile`. 2) Then you have to close and delete this `tmp` file *explicitly*. So, add this two lines: `tmp.close()` and `os.unlink(tmp.name)` after `stream = tmp.read()`.  Don't forget to `import os`, of course :). I took this solution from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54768241/3366563)

Answer (score 5):

this worked for me

```
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
from openpyxl.writer.excel import save_virtual_workbook

wb = Workbook()
...

response = HttpResponse(content=save_virtual_workbook(wb), content_type='application/ms-excel')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=Inform.xlsx'
return response
```